# How to draw \psellipticarc?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(4,4)
\psellipticarc[showpoints]{->}(.5,0)(1.5,1){215}{0}
\psarc*[showpoints](1.5,1.5){1.5}{215}{0}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Update:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(4,4)
\psarc*[showpoints](1.5,1.5){1.5}{215}{0}
\psellipticarc[showpoints]{->}(.5,0)(1.5,1){215}{0}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces true result

[image]
Question:

How to fix it?

How to the star version be more beautiful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(4,4)
%
\psellipticarc[linecolor=red,correctAngle=false]{->}(1,2)(1,2){215}{0}
\rput(1,2){%
    \psset{linestyle=dashed}%
    \psline(!1 2 215 PtoCab)(0,0)%
    \psline(0,0)(!1 2 0 PtoCab)}
%
\psarc*(3,3){1}{215}{0}
\rput(3,3){%
    \psset{linestyle=dashed}%
    \psline(!1 215 PtoC)(0,0)%
    \psline(0,0)(!1 0 PtoC)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## About `correctAngle`

An ellipse can be parameterized as  `x=a cos t` and `y= b sin t` where `t` is a parameter that does not represent an angle relative to the `x` axis.

If you write, for example `\psellipticalarc(0,0)(1,2){0}{45}` with the default `correctAngle=true` then it draws an elliptical arc that starts from 0 degrees to 45 degrees.

However, if you write, for example `\psellipticalarc[correctAngle=false](0,0)(1,2){0}{45}` then it draw an elliptical arc that starts from 0 degrees to `arctan(2)` degrees.  Here 45 does not represent an angle relative to the x axis.

Thus, `correctAngle=true` can be read as "make the parameter as a **real** angle".

Answer (score 2):

With `pstricks.tex` from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pstricks/

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(5,4)
    \psarc[showpoints](0.25,0.5){1.5}{215}{0}
    \psarc*(3.25,2){1.5}{215}{0}
    \psarc(3.25,0.5){1.5}{215}{0}
    \psarc*[showpoints](0.25,2){1.5}{215}{0}
    \psellipticarc[showpoints,linecolor=red](0,3)(1.5,1){215}{0}
    \psellipticarc*[showpoints,linecolor=red](0,4)(1.5,1){215}{0}
    \psellipticarc[linecolor=red](3,3)(1.5,1){215}{0}
    \psellipticarc*[linecolor=red](3,4)(1.5,1){215}{0}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For `correctAngle` read http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-news10.pdf  section 3.4, page 8

Comment: With \psarc*[showpoints](0.25,2){1.5}{215}{0} and \psellipticarc*[showpoints,linecolor=red](0,4)(1.5,1){215}{0} , it poduces dash line belong black area. Ugly. How to ignore it?

Comment: It is obviously, that `showpoints` will draw the help lines. Do not use it if you do not want it!

Comment: @Herbert \psarc*(1.5,1.5){1.5}{215}{0}
 \psarc[showpoints](1.5,1.5){1.5}{215}{0} are more beautiful \psarc*[showpoints](1.5,1.5){1.5}{215}{0}. Are you ok?

Comment: I already wrote: That are _help lines_ to see where the origin is. If you want other lines then use `\psline`!

Comment: Yes, I see ah. :-)