# Drawing an elliptic arc using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, draw, arc, ellipsis

I can't figure out the command for drawing an elliptic arc having vertical radius 2 cm and horizontal radius 5 cm using "PSTricks".
I am just a beginniner so please help.

Comment: Use `\psellipticarc`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467769/33933 for examples

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. I hope you manage to solve the issue, e.g. by the question Christoph linked above!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
 \begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,4)
\psellipticarc[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=red](5,2)(5,2){0}{270}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]